# How to migrate from Windows phone 8.1 to UWP?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying to migrate my windows phone 8.1 app to UWP. After following all the [steps for migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx), while reloading project, I am getting the following error:

G:\My apps\PhoneApp8\PhoneApp8\phoneapp8.csproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft...Overrides.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  G:\My apps\PhoneApp8\PhoneApp8\phoneapp8.csproj

I am using visual studio 2015 professional. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Create a new UWP app, copy your files over and start rewriting code.

Comment: This is actually the best solution - no idea why it was downvoted.

Comment: I was gonna try this as a final solution

Comment: @thewarri0r9 yes this is the way to go it sounds daunting but you probably can reuse 95% of the code. Remember to set `TargetDeviceFamily` to `Windows.Mobile` if you only want the app to appear on phones

Comment: @igor I tried that and got like 200+ errors. Apparently windows 10 sdk doesn't support many libraries from windows 8.1.

Comment: Yes, that is why I talk about rewriting :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the project in an older Visual Studio version? If yes, you probably have to change the Visual Studio version in the .csproj file. Take a look at [this](http://sedodream.com/2012/08/19/VisualStudioProjectCompatabilityAndVisualStudioVersion.aspx).

Comment: yes but I changed visual studio version to 14.0 in .csproj file still getting the same error